# Favicon not working

Tags: html, favicon

I can not get my browser icon to load.

```
<link rel="icon" href="pics/favicon.ico"/>
```

Also tried:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="pics/favicon.ico"/>
```

<s>When I open up Chrome developer tools and click the link to the ico file, I received a 404 error. The path is correct I have double and triple checked.</s> Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT** I changed the file name to favicon and now the browser can find it but it does not render in the tab or address bar.

**EDIT1** Icon size is 64x64. Thats not too big or is it?

Comment: Have you tried `/pics/favicon.ico` Could be a relative path problem. What's the url of the HTML page that's hosting that link tag?

Comment: Just tried putting in in the root. and same result.

Comment: I don't know whats going on. when i click the link to the resource in chrome dev. it pulls the icon into the browser but when i refresh my page it doesn't work even after clearing cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have my icon on a server. It was on my local machine. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the favicon.ico exists on the server. If you're getting a 404 when you go to view the file, the only answer is that either the path is wrong, or the file doesn't exist.

EDIT:

*rel="shortcut icon"* is correct. Try clearing your cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it's hard to refresh favicon from cache. But if you are using Google Chrome, just clean your cache end after that refresh your page.